# Entering website domain name from within the LAN takes me to my router configuration instead of the website

Tags: dns, webserver

I know this question has already been asked here, but it wasn't specific enough to my needs and it was asked way back in 2011. I have a web server running on my PC. I keep getting taken to the router configuration instead of the actual website when I enter my site's hostname (note that I'm using No-IP for dynamic DNS) instead of the actual website. Outside of the LAN, the website can be accessed without a hitch. My router is a Huawei HG533.
Output of nslookup command

Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  1.1.1.1

Name:    credence.ddns.net
Address:  92.12.162.46

Comment: What IP address is being returned for the hostname when you are inside the network? Use `nslookup` and find out. Please don’t respond with “my router IP.” The problem is either a DNS issue or a port forwarding issue. Please edit your question with this information. Also, please remove the last half of your post as it doesn’t support the actual question.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: As suggested this is probably a port forwarding issue called hairpin NAT. If the router doesn’t support it then you need to come up with workarounds. A lot of home routers will allow you to create static DNS entries. If so, you could add the hostname to a static DNS entry and specify the servers internal IP. In this way, users inside the network will receive an internal IP address for the server. This is called split-DNS and is often the way this type of scenario is handled. If the router doesn’t support it then you could setup a new DNS server for the internal users to use.

Comment: If I set up a new DNS server, will I need to change my router's DNS settings to point to the DNS server?

Comment: No. You would change the DHCP settings on the router so that all devices on the network receive and use a different DNS IP address.

Comment: Would it just be a case of creating a forward lookup zone for ddns.net on my Win2k server?

Comment: Yes you would create a zone for ddns.net and add in the records you need using the internal IPs. Forward all other requests (using the Forwarders options) back to your router or ISP. Point all internal devices to the new DNS server via DHCP on the router.

Comment: I did some research online. If my understanding is correct, I would create a new host in the ddns.net zone called credence.ddns.net and set the IP address to 192.168.1.205 (the internal IP of the web server) and then use the afore mentioned forwarders option to forward the requests back to the router.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple router, so I don't think it supports connections that go out to the Internet and come back again from the outside.

Only high-end (and costly) routers can do that.

The manual of the Huawei HG533 that I found contains next to no information at all,
so I don't know of a way to set it up such that the request will stay inside
the network and will not go out to the Internet.

I believe that what you are seeing is the router telling you it can't do the request,
or perhaps that something needs to be configured.

Comment: Connections to the router's own address do not go out to the Internet; they go to the router and nowhere further... I'm not sure if hairpinning is a feature exclusive to "high-end" routers; it's certainly not universal but it seemed much more common than that.